# iFrame does not display if logged out Google (or give instructions to log back in)

Tags: google-drive-api

I have displayed a form using the iframe tool in Google docs (file>embed from the doc/form you want to share.)

It works well except if you happen to be logged out of your google account. If you are logged out, it doesn't appear or even prompt you to login to your google account to see it.

Is there something I am doing wrong within google docs? I have tried changing the privacy settings and even made it public.

Is there any way to display a message if you are not logged in, asking you to (somehow) login?

Comment: can you attach some sample code that you tried?

Comment: really is no code - just an iframe embed 

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/company.com/forms/d/1ROPYWlcHwcV2DaH6qhk7UP9upkgbSE-yT6UYoJaxDAY/viewform?embedded=true" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>

Answer (score -1):

Your iframe code (as it displays in StackOverflow) is malformed, close the double quotes after the link.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/company.com/forms/d/1ROPYWlcHwcV2DaH6qhk7UP9upkgbSE-yT6UYoJaxDAY/viewform?embedded=true%22" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Comment: iframe source was pasted incorrectly, my apologies

   <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/company.com/forms/d/1ROPYWlcHwcV2DaH6qhk7UP9upkgbSE-yT6UYoJaxDAY/viewform?embedded=true" width="100%" height="2500px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="overflow: hidden;">Loading...</iframe>